# python3 ImportError: cannot import name 'rand_str'

Tags: python

Im getting this error when starting my software i dont know how to repair this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/findex/lib/python3.5/site-packages/findex_gui/main.py", line 208, in web
    run_async()
  File "/root/findex/lib/python3.5/site-packages/findex_gui/main.py", line 201, in run_async
    from findex_gui.web import app
  File "/root/findex/lib/python3.5/site-packages/findex_gui/web.py", line 41, in <module>
    from findex_gui.orm.connect import Database
  File "/root/findex/lib/python3.5/site-packages/findex_gui/orm/connect.py", line 12, in <module>
    from findex_gui.orm.models import BASE
  File "/root/findex/lib/python3.5/site-packages/findex_gui/orm/models.py", line 22, in <module>
    from findex_common.utils import rand_str
ImportError: cannot import name 'rand_str'
```

Comment: To my knowledge there is nothing known as 'rand_str' in the standard library. If it is something you wrote you have given absolutely nothing that could help anyone diagnose your import error, i.e. the source code. Please read the rules about how to properly ask a question on SO and edit your question to include the pertinent information.

Comment: Do you mean [RandString](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RandString), cause there is nothing called rand_str.

Comment: probably bug in source code, it should be `from findex_common.utils import random_str`, line 144: https://github.com/skftn/findex-common/blob/master/findex_common/utils.py#L144

Comment: @ktb the relevant line which contains the import is in the stacktrace though it's difficult to read in the current state, viewing the not-yet-approved edit makes it more obvious what is going on

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the libraries in question, but it seems the maintainer renamed this function in 0.15.14 of `findex-common` here: [development](https://github.com/skftn/findex-common/commit/4abbc31be91c6cee7500e83c7e2d2fb7e3fb31df)

This has been adjusted for in `findex-gui` on the master branch though it seems it has not seen a release.  Here's the commit which fixes the import: [Forgot what I was doing - Ill just push it all ¯_(ツ)_/¯](https://github.com/skftn/findex-gui/commit/b5798b2b33b1e6b346cddfaefc88bf13b848eedd)

One short term fix would be to downgrade to `findex-common==0.15.13` and perhaps follow up by raising an issue on [either](https://github.com/skftn/findex-common) [project](https://github.com/skftn/findex-gui) since the change seems non-ideal.